# How to reverse a Simple Queue(FIFO) using one more Simple Queue(FIFO)?

Tags: data-structures, queue

Let us take an first Queue which contain elements 1,2,3,4 in order so the first Queue becomes 1,2,3,4 front is 1 and rear is 4. We have one more empty Queue contains zero elements. How can we reverse this first Queue using another Queue which is empty ? (We cannot use third Queue for reversing).

I have tried to reverse a Queue using one more Queue but no solution comes in my brain.

So I expect the Queue to be reversed so that first Queue elements become 4,3,2,1 after reversing.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def rotate(q, k):
    move(q, q, k)

def move(q1, q2, k):
    for i in range(k):
        q2.append(q1.pop(0))


def reverse(q1):
    q2 = []
    for i in range(1, len(q1)):
        move(q1, q2, len(q1) - i)
        rotate(q2, len(q2) - 1)
        move(q2, q1, len(q2))
        rotate(q1, i + 1)

    return q1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
        rq =  reverse(range(i))
        assert rq == range(i)[::-1]
```